# Rails How to find weekly Login count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to count the weekly login of a particular user. Now I have login_count in my Db User model.

I want to find the user with maximum login count for every week, every month and every year.

What is the nice way to implement this in Rails?

In User.rb

```
                          :id 
                        :name 
                       :email 
           :persistence_token 
            :crypted_password
               :password_salt
                   :school_id 
                     :deleted 
                  :created_at 
                  :updated_at
                      :mobile
                     :year_id 
                 :original_id
         :subscription_status 
                 :login_count 
          :failed_login_count
            :current_login_ip 
               :last_login_ip
            :current_login_at 
               :last_login_at
```

Now I have a tracking_logins model which captures user_id, login_time

Now what i have done to get the user login count is

```
      user_login_hash = school_logins.group(:user_id).count
```

What should I do to find weekly login count of a particular user?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In order to accomplish this, you need to rethink the login count approach. Instead of capturing a simple count, you need to capture each time a user logs in and the date. Then you can apply proper login counters and a breakdown by date ranges.

Comment: Actually I have the last_login_date also in my model. Let me Edit my Question so you can understand better. THank you.

Comment: I understand your question. The last login date is not enough data to find the user with the highest login count. The only statistic you will have is the highest login count of all time.

Comment: Okay. But is there any brilliant way to implement this without capturing the login date every time?

Comment: No, you need to create a new table that will store two fields: user_id and current datetime. Then you can be brilliant, and solve your task.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant guidance.This will help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at "[public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity)" gem, it would be easier to implement and get your task done.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user model, if you used it, so you can use sign_in_count by [devise-models-trackable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable).

For your question, you need to create new model as example `Activity` has these fields `user_id`, `login_date`, and `login_count`.